# 2D Matrix-Visualization as Heatmap, Multithreaded c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, heatmap

I´m currently working on a c# winform-application, in this application I want to visualize a 2d-matrix as a heat-map. The matrix is altered within another thread roughly 50 times per second.

I do not want to slow down the working thread by the visualization, so I suppose using a lock would be counter-productive. Moreover, the visualization may miss some matrix-changes, updating the visualization a few times per second is sufficient.

I´m unsure how I should proceed and hope someone can point me in the right direction?!